# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "macundales"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, etimología, significado, venezuela

He escuchado muchas veces a personas conversando y entre lo que se dicen:

> Agarra tus **macundales** y te vas...

Según el DAMER:

> [**macundales**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=macundales).
>   I.  1.  m. pl. Ve. Enseres, utensilios de uso personal. ◆ macundos.

Ahora bien, el origen de dicha frase ¿de dónde proviene?

¿De dónde proviene esta palabra o cuál es su significado original?
¿Tiene traducción al inglés?

Comment: David, tus preguntas son interesantes y todos estamos aprendiendo de ellas. De todos modos, fíjate que en las sucesivas respuestas que has recibido hemos proporcionado una serie de recursos como el DAMER en el que puedes buscar información. Por ello, sería interesante que además de preguntar, indicaras qué buscaste y qué no encontraste, para evitar repetir lo que ya sabes.

Comment: Pregunta editada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En [etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?macundales) hablan de ello y mencionan que la palabra proviene de la marca de herramientas americanas *Mack & Dales*:

> La palabra **macundales** proviene de una deformación de la palabra Mack & Dales que era una marca de herramientas norteamericanas en la época de los inicios de la explotación minera y petrolera en Venezuela. Al terminar la jornada laboral las herramientas se dejaban en el terreno y los compañeros de trabajo decían: "Oye toma tus Mack & Dales" y se fue deformando de tanto decirlo que se abrevio finalmente diciendo "Oye toma tus macundales" Ahora la palabra se utiliza para describir un objeto o grupo de objetos que se deben recoger.